# How to arrange content in printed tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to arrange content in a tuple to fit a specific column layout.

Example layout:

```
PETER PAUL            MALE            100000
MARGARET              FEMALE          1000
MICHAEL JORDAN        MALE            1
AGNES                 FEMALE          200
```

But when I iterate over the tuple to print the contents, it outputs:

```
PETER PAUL            MALE            100000
MARGARET             FEMALE            1000
MICHAEL JORDAN            MALE            1
AGNES            FEMALE            200
```

Also when I `return row`, it only returns the first `tuple` and not all of them. I am returning it because I want to use it in another function.

This is the code below:

```
def text():
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"), ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))

    for row in rows:
       # print("          ".join(row))
        print("".join(row[0]), "".join("          "), "".join(row[1]), "".join("          "), "".join(row[2]))
        #return row

text()
```

I use the `join` method, but I couldn't find `ljust`, which I think is no longer available in `python3`.

Comment: Use `.format()` or f-strings.

Comment: please can you demonstrate it for me or any link to find the documentation on that

Comment: Don't you know how to look up the documentation of built-in Python functions? Just google "python format".

Answer (score 4):

Use Python's string [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format) to give each of your elements a fixed width:

```
def text():
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"), ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))

    for row in rows:
        print('{:20} {:8} {}'.format(*row))

text()
```

Giving you:

```
PETER PAUL           MALE     100000
MARGARET             FEMALE   1000
MICHAEL JORDAN       MALE     1
AGNES                FEMALE   200
```

The `format()` command works by replacing each `{}` seen in the string by an argument passed to it, in this case `*row`. The `*` has the effect of expanding the three values inside `row` to be the three arguments required to be expanded.

---

To return the formatted text, you would need to first create a list of formatted rows, and then use `'\n'.join()` to join them all together will newlines at the end:

```
def text():
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"), ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))

    data = []

    for row in rows:
        data.append('{:20} {:8} {}'.format(*row))

    return '\n'.join(data)

print(text())
```

This could also be done very neatly using a Python "list comprehension" as follows:

```
def text():
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"), ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))
    return '\n'.join('{:20} {:8} {}'.format(*row) for row in rows)

print(text())
```

Comment: When I use return it returns only the first tuple how can make it to return all the content

Comment: Why not use `return rows` ?

Comment: It doesn't work once i bring return there it returns only the first tuple

Comment: Are you wanting to return all of the formatted text?

Comment: Yes just like the printed one on the terminal

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how this can be done.

Comment: when i return the the content for another function it output `PETER PAUL MALE 100000MARGARET FEMALE 1000MICHAEL JORDAN` not like the how it printed to the terminal the second function.

Comment: How are you printing this? What is your environment? For example, if you tried printing this as HTML, you would lose all the spaces and the newlines would also vanish.

Comment: printing through printer , want to save it as pdf file through `foxit reader PDF Printer` pywin32 module.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing more code. You could though try using `\r\n` instead of `\n` for the newlines. Also, you will probably need to print using a fixed width font. The default font is probably proportional, .e.g. "W" and "I" have different widths, and spaces never line up. You might want to start a new separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline formating:

```
def text():
    t = []
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"),  ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), 
            ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),   ("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))

    for row in rows:
        t.append(f'{row[0]:<30}{row[1]:<10}{row[2]:<20}') 

    return t

for n in text():
    print(n)
```

Output:

```
PETER PAUL                    MALE      100000              
MARGARET                      FEMALE    1000                
MICHAEL JORDAN                MALE      1                   
AGNES                         FEMALE    200
```

Formatting:

- [formatting language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec)

`<20` for strings is not needed as left-adjust is the default, if you need to right-adjust use `>20`. See link for more infos about formatting language constructs.

Comment: When I use return it returns only the first tuple how can make it to return all the content

Comment: @LAS Updated to return all strings as list - they do not have \n at end, you you need to add that or print the strings separately

Comment: when i return the the content for another function it output `PETER PAUL MALE 100000MARGARET FEMALE 1000MICHAEL JORDAN` not like the how it printed to the terminal .how can it be that the second tuple will state from newline

Comment: @Las - you did read my last comment - did you? use `'\n'.join(text())+'\n'` to have a newline after each line or use `'linesWithNewlineAtEnd = [f'{x}\n' for x in test()]` to create a list that includes newlines - or modify `'t.append(f'{row[0]:<30}{row[1]:<10}{row[2]:<20}')'` to `'t.append(f'{row[0]:<30}{row[1]:<10}{row[2]:<20}\n')'` - try to understand the solution you copy and modify it to your needs...